# Perl internal variables. Are next expressions same?

Tags: perl

I have two expressions:

```
${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" }
```

and

```
${ "::_<$filename" }
```

are these two expressions same?

Comment: `$filename = __FILE__; ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" } eq ${ "::_<$filename" };` returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but the following are equivalent:

```
${"_<$filename"}         # When this expression is found in package main
${"::_<$filename"}
${"main::_<$filename"}

${ $::{"_<$filename"} }
${ ${'::'}{"_<$filename"} }

${ $main::{"_<$filename"} }
${ ${'main::'}{"_<$filename"} }
```

These are refer to the variable in the root/main namespace whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`.

---

As a clearer example, the following are all equivalent (assuming the code is compiled in package `Foo::Bar` for the first two):

```
@moo                                  # Via hardcoded, unqualified name
@{'moo'}                              # Via symref using unqualified name

@Foo::Bar::moo                        # Via hardcoded, qualified name
@{'Foo::Bar::moo'}                    # Via symref using qualified name

@{ *Foo::Bar::moo }                   # Via hardcoded glob
@{ *{'Foo::Bar::moo'} }               # Via symref to glob

@{ $Foo::Bar::{moo} }                 # Via glob via hardcoded package
@{ ${'Foo::Bar::'}{moo} }             # Via glob via symref to package

@{ $Foo::{'Bar::'}{moo} }             # Via glob via hardcoded parent package
@{ ${'Foo'}::{'Bar::'}{moo} }         # Via glob via symref to parent package

@{ $::{'Foo::'}{'Bar::'}{moo} }       # Via glob via root package
@{ $main::{'Foo::'}{'Bar::'}{moo} }   # Same
```

---

Perl allows symbol names to be used as references.

```
$ perl -e'%h = ( a => 4, b => 5 ); my $ref = "h"; CORE::say $ref->{a};'
4
```

These are called "symbolic references" (and they're not allowed when using `use strict;`). The following uses `main::` as a symbolic reference:

```
${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" }
```

There's no point to doing that, however. Since the name of the variable is hardcoded anyway, we might as well use the following:

```
$main::{ "_<$filename" }
```

Not only is this simpler, it's allowed when using `use strict;`.

---

But what is `%main::`? Well, that's the symbol table for the package `main`. The keys of `%main::` are the names of the symbols (variables) that exist in the package `main` (without any sigil).

The values of `%main::` are symbol table entries. We call these "typeglobs", or "globs" for short. Dereferencing a glob as if it was a reference access the variable of the type appropriate for the dereference. For example,

```
$main::{a}
```

returns

```
*main::a       # A glob
```

and

```
${ $main::{a} }
```

returns

```
$main::a
```

This means that the following returns a glob to the variable in the `main` namespace whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`

```
$main::{ "_<$filename" }
```

---

The main namespace is also the root namespace. This means that

```
$main::a
```

and

```
$::a
```

both refer to the same variable. It also means that

```
%main::
```

and

```
%::
```

both refer to the same variable. It also means that

```
$main::{ "_<$filename" }
```

and

```
$::{ "_<$filename" }
```

both return the same glob.

---

We've established that the following returns a glob to the symbol in the root/main namespace whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`

```
$::{ "_<$filename" }
```

We've also established that the following references the scalar in the root/main whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`:

```
${ $::{ "_<$filename" } }
```

And finally, we've also established that following is a symbolic reference that references the same scalar:

```
${ "::_<$filename" }
```

Comment: very detailed explanation. thank you. Does documentation exist for this?

Comment: I suspect that all of this is documented, though not all in one place.

Comment: [`%::` and `%main::`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables). (Not much detail.)

Comment: [Globs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles). (Mostly about working with `STDOUT` and creating an alias.) There's more about them [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables).

Answer (score 4):

Almost

`${ "::_<$filename" }` is the scalar variable in the default/`main` namespace with the name given by `"_<$filename"`

`%{"main::"}` is the stash variable for the default/`main` namespace, and
`${"main::"}{"_<$filename"}` is a typeglob which can be *derefenced* with any of the dereferencing operators to retrieve the values in the `main` namespace with the name given by `"_<$filename"`.

So it's these two expressions are equivalent:

```
${"::_<$filename"}
${${"main::"}{"_<$filename"}}
```

A short demo:

```
$ perl -de 1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> $main::foo = 42                                                                                    

  DB<2> @main::foo = (1,2,3,"bacon")                                                                       

  DB<3> x ${"main::"}{"foo"}                                                                               
0  *main::foo
  DB<4> x ${${"main::"}{"foo"}}, @{${"main::"}{"foo"}}                                                     
0  42
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  'bacon' 
  DB<5> x @{"::foo"}, ${"::foo"}                                                                           
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  'bacon'
4  42
```

Comment: Congratulations on 100k :)))

Comment: I'd also add (as discussed on IRC) that since `%main::` is the package stash, `$main::{foo}` is actually a ref to the typeglob containing the variable as well as the other package variables sharing its name, which is why dereferencing it as a scalar gives you the scalar. `@{$main::{foo}}` instead would give you `@main::foo`. And in all these cases `main::` and `::` are of course equivalent.

Comment: Also, these typeglob accesses are confusing and almost always unnecessary. Use [Package::Stash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Stash) if you really need to access the stash.

Comment: @Grinnz, Yeah, avoiding globs is good. These are really internal structures, and there's a couple of ways in which they can surprise you. No need for that package, though; just use a symbolic references (e.g. `${ "::_<$filename" }` instead of `${ $::{ "_<$filename" } }`)