# Why these two variables `${ "_<$filename" }` and `${ "::_<$filename" }` not equal?

Tags: perl

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56260910/4632019) one.

You say that these two are same:

```
${ "::_<$filename" }                       # Not allowed under strict.
${ "_<$filename" }     # In main package   # Not allowed under strict.
```

But how then next is possible?

```
if( ${ "_<$filename" } ne ${ "::_<$filename" } ) {
    print "MISMATCH\n";
    print ">>${ '_<$filename' }<<\n>>${ '::_<$filename' }<<\n";
}
```

output:

```
MISMATCH
>><<
>><<
```

this happens when `$filename` is `/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm`

**UPD**
with `"` quotes as `@HåkonHægland` advised

```
    print "MISMATCH\n";
    print ">>${ \"_<$filename\" }<<\n>>${ \"::_<$filename\" }<<\n";
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${         "_<$filename"  } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${       "::_<$filename"  } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${     $::{"_<$filename"} } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${ ${'::'}{"_<$filename"} } );
```

output is:

```
MISMATCH
>><<
>>/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm<<
SV = PV(0xfb84520) at 0xff527a0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()
  PV = 0
SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2edc4a0 "/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm"\0
  CUR = 111
  LEN = 113
  COW_REFCNT = 0
SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2edc4a0 "/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm"\0
  CUR = 111
  LEN = 113
  COW_REFCNT = 0
SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2edc4a0 "/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm"\0
  CUR = 111
  LEN = 113
  COW_REFCNT = 0
```

From the output we can see that topic variables are different:

```
SV = PV(0xfb84520) at 0xff527a0
SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
```

Comment: It works for me (does not print `MISMATCH`). I tried with the `$filename` you gave and then set `${ "_<$filename" } = "Hello"`

Comment: You also should not use single quotes in `print ">>${ '_<$filename' }<<\n"`. Instead try: `print ">>${ \"_<$filename\" }<<\n"`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Unfortunately this is only one small part of code at big application. I bother this because my debugger is died at this point. I am investigating why that happens.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: 2: This is surprise for me. Never thought that perl distinguish `"` and `'` at that context. Notice. I have updated output. But then `${ "::_<$filename" }` and `${ "_<$filename" }` are not the same thing as @ikegami noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268691/4632019)

Comment: *"... are not the same thing ..."* Yes, you are right. I tried in package `main`, but if I change to `package foo` they are different yes

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I missed that  `::` mean `main` package

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@HåkonHægland`. I missed that `::` mean `main` package.

I was messed up by:

> the following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> ${ "::_<$filename" }                       # Not allowed under strict.
> ${ "_<$filename" }     # In main package   # Not allowed under strict.
> ```

Now I understand that means

```
${ "::_<$filename" }   # This refers to a var in main package
${ "_<$filename" }     # This refers to a var in CURRENT! package
```

Comment: It seems `ikegami` updated [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268691/4632019) too. Thank you @ikegami

Comment: I didn't say `${ "_<$filename" }` referred to a variable in the main package; I said *`${ "::_<$filename" }`* is equivalent to *`${ "_<$filename" }` in main package*. If `${ "_<$filename" }` is found in different package, it won't be equivalent to `${ "::_<$filename" }`. Fixed misquote.

Comment: That said, I agree it was written in a confusing manner. To that end, I rewrote that part of the Answer in question (long before seeing this Q&A), and I've just made it even clearer.