# Why these two variables `${ $::{"_<$filename"} }` and `${ “::_<$filename” }` not equal?

Tags: perl

This question belongs to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56270222/4632019) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268691/4632019)

@ikegami says:

---

We've established that the following returns a glob to the symbol in the root/main namespace whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`

```
$::{ "_<$filename" }
```

We've also established that the following references the scalar in the root/main whose name is produced by `"_<$filename"`:

```
${ $::{ "_<$filename" } }
```

And finally, we've also established that following is a symbolic reference that references the same scalar:

```
${ "::_<$filename" }
```

---

While debugging my app I write next code at the debugger:

```
DB::say "EXISTS";
defined ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" }? DB::say "YES" : DB::say "NO";
defined ${ "::_<$filename" }? DB::say "YES" : DB::say "NO";
if( ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" } ne ${ "::_<$filename" } ) {
    print "MISMATCH\n";
    print "$filename\n";
    print ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" }, "\n",
        defined ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" }, "\n",
        ${ "::_<$filename" }, "\n",
        defined ${ "::_<$filename" }, "\n";
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${ ${ 'main::' }{ "_<$filename" } } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${       "::_<$filename"  } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${     $::{"_<$filename"} } );
    Devel::Peek::Dump( ${ ${'::'}{"_<$filename"} } );
}
```

The output is:

```
EXISTS
YES
NO
MISMATCH
Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint
*main::_<Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint
1


SV = PV(0x14f6a30) at 0x184b200
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x1849990 "Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint"\0
  CUR = 49
  LEN = 51
SV = PV(0xe1f5f50) at 0xe5b9438
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()
  PV = 0
SV = PV(0x14f6a30) at 0x184b200
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x1849990 "Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint"\0
  CUR = 49
  LEN = 51
SV = PV(0x14f6a30) at 0x184b200
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x1849990 "Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint"\0
  CUR = 49
  LEN = 51
```

NOTICE: when `$filename` is `Specio::Constraint::Simple->_optimized_constraint` variables **are different**:

```
$::{ "_<$filename" }      # SV = PV(0xe1f5f50) at 0xe5b9438
${ $::{ "_<$filename" } } # SV = PV(0x14f6a30) at 0x184b200
```

but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56270222/4632019) (see UPD section) when `$filename` is 
`/home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/app/maitre_d/../..//local/lib/perl5/Specio/Constraint/Role/Interface.pm` variables **are same**:

```
$::{ "_<$filename" }             # SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
${ $::{ "_<$filename" } }        # SV = PV(0x2e43d80) at 0x2f40400
```

Comment: *"Specio::Constraint::Simple"* seems to be related to the double colons in the name somehow.. If I remove them it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your variable `$filename` contains double colons, so when used as part of a symbolic reference, those double colons will be interpreted as namespace separators. Going directly through the symbol table (stash) does not interpret them as separators, as namespaces are distinguished by the physical stash hierarchy. Thus to access variables whose symbol names may contain double colons, direct stash access is needed. Normally I would recommend [Package::Stash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Stash) for such dealings with the stash, but it disallows accessing symbol names containing double colons because it's impossible to use them normally as variables.